# How to prove $B-A \succeq 0 \Leftrightarrow$ ellipsoid $x^TBx \leq 1$ contains $x^TAx \leq 1$?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, analytic-geometry, matrix-calculus, ellipsoids

Assume $A \in \textbf{S}^n_{++}$, an ellipsoid centered at the origin given by

$$\mathcal{E}_A = \{x\mid x^TA^{-1}x \leq 1\}$$

Then we have $\mathcal{E}_A \subseteq \mathcal{E}_B $ if and only if $B-A \succeq 0$.

This is the proposition in the Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook) (pages 45-46). The authors gave only the result, without proof. How to prove it?

[image: Boyd and Vandenberghe, Convex Optimization, Page 45-46]

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://systemanalysisdpt-cmc-msu.github.io/ellipsoids/doc/chap_ellcalc.html#checking-if-one-ellipsoid-contains-another) and [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/lmi-s-proc.pdf).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/395782/339790

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\varepsilon_A =  \{ x \mid x^T A^{-1}x \le 1 \} $ is the set of points  that comprise the inner ellipsoid and $\varepsilon_B =  \{ x |\; x^T B^{-1}x \le 1 \} $ be the set of points comprising the outer ellipsoid and the two ellipsoid are distinct. Since $B-A \succeq 0$ is a PSD and since both $A,B$ have inverses $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ (the inverses exist) we can say

$$B-A \succeq 0 \Rightarrow I-B^{-1}A\succeq 0 \Rightarrow A^{-1}-B^{-1}\succeq 0$$

therefore $A^{-1}-B^{-1}$ is PSD and we can conclude that for every $x$ we have $x^T(A^{-1}-B^{-1})x\ge 0 \Rightarrow x^TA^{-1}x\ge x^TB^{-1}x $. This means that $\forall x\in \varepsilon_A : 1\ge x^TA^{-1}x \ge x^TB^{-1}x \Rightarrow x\in \varepsilon_B$.

Conversely assume $\forall x\in \varepsilon_A \Rightarrow x\in \varepsilon_B$ and assume that instead $A-B \succeq 0$ (contradiction assumption), which with a similar reasoning gives us $\forall x\in \varepsilon_B \Rightarrow x\in \varepsilon_A$ which states that both ellipsoids are the same and equivalent which is a contradiction (since we assumed they are distinct) and therefore the  result follows.

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I can't understand why $B-A \succeq 0 \Rightarrow I-B^{-1}A\succeq 0 \Rightarrow A^{-1}-B^{-1}\succeq 0$. Can you give detailed proof about it? Since the multiplication of two PSD matrix isn't PSD all the time.

Comment: Why positive semi-definite, $A,B \in \textbf{S}^n_{++}$, they are positive-definite and the product of two positive-definite is positive-definite (using Cholesky, $A = LL^H$ thus $AB = LL^HB = L (L^HBL)L^{-1}$ and therefore $AB$ is similar to $L^HBL$ and positive definite). Also if $A$ is PD then $A^{-1}$ is also PD. $$B \succeq A \Rightarrow I \succeq B^{-1}A \Rightarrow A^{-1} \succeq B^{-1}$$

Comment: I get your point. But since $I - B^{-1}A$ isn't symmetric, maybe using eigenvalues is more rigid？
$ B-A \succeq 0$ and $ B \succ 0 $ we can get eigenvalues of $ I - B^{-1}A $ are nonnegative, Similarly eigenvalues of $ A^{-1} - B^{-1} $ are nonnegative. Combine with $ A^{-1} - B^{-1} $ is Hermitian then PSD.

Comment: Yes you are right, I did not notice $B^{-1}A$ is not symmetric therefore we can't conclude the result. It's actually the generalization of simple inequality $a>b>0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{b}>\frac{1}{a}>0$ to generalized matrix inequality but it's not a trivial task at all and you need solid functional analysis which is above my pay grade, but if you get that result as a prove fact, then the rest follows. If you want I delete the answer and all comments will be removed too, just tell me to remove it and sorry for disappointment.

Comment: No your answer is very inspiring and this fact is completely right. I found the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882705/if-a-succeq-b-is-it-true-that-b-1-succeq-a-1). By this I believe the answer can be perfect. If you like you can add this to your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Nice, I saw the answer you mentioned, PSD proof can be done with inner product definition very efficiently. thanks!

Comment: @wz0919 The statement $I - B^{-1}A \succeq 0$ is incorrect in general. It is true however that $I - B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2} \succeq 0$